# orderBy по количеству символов laravel

Tags: laravel

Возможно ли отсортировать запрос по количеству символов в поле?
Например:

```
$post= Post::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->get();
```

Он отсортирует по алфавиту(а-я), а нужно по количеству символов

Сделал `сырым запросом`

```
$post= DB::select('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(title) ASC');
```

Может можно обойтись без него?

Comment: Ну будет что-то вроде `orderByRaw('LENGTH(title) ASC')`.

Comment: @Akina Пишет, что нет такого столбца `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LENGTH(title)' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from 'post' order by 'LENGTH(title)' asc)`, столбец title присутствует

Comment: Текст запроса ``select * from `post` order by LENGTH(title) asc``, в таблице post есть поле title, но выдаётся показанное сообщение об ошибке? Или текущая БД - не та, в ней случайно есть такая таблица, но с иной структурой, или этого не может быть. Ну не считая экзотики типа того, что последняя буква в имени поля - кириллическая... (PS. Если в тексте запроса есть обратная кавычка - обрамляйте его двойными обратными кавычками, а не одинарными).

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, помогло использование `orderByRaw`